# phpseclib always produces login failed

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm not sure if this is me doing something wrong or whether the server just doesn't support phpseclib or what, but I am trying to connect to an FTP server that will only accept secure FTP connections, and only from certain IP addresses. Now I know that the FTP server accepts a connection from my VPS server as I have remotely connected into my VPS via SSH and manually connected to the FTP server from the command line successfully.

However when I try the following with phpseclib it always hits the exit point.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include 'Net/SFTP.php';

$sftp = new NET_SFTP('***');
if(!$sftp->login('***', '***')) {
    $sftp->getSFTPErrors();
    exit('Login Failed'); // <-- Code always gets to this point
}

echo $sftp->pwd();
```

I am unsure on how to even begin debugging this problem. I have [asked a question on their forum](http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=168858&p=392293) as well to try and get help. I have tried to enable logging with `define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);` and then output `echo $sftp->getSFTPLog();` just above the exit, but that doesn't output anything.

On the page I have just `Login Failed`, so I'm not getting any errors from `$sftp->getSFTPErrors();`.

I am completely new to using a secure FTP connection in PHP and don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me debug the issue?

Comment: Looks like you've gotten an answer here?: http://www.frostjedi.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=168858

Comment: Did you find what the final problem was? Since I am getting the same error.

Comment: @MasnadNihit the server was missing a needed module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're using it it's clear that you don't see any errors.
`$sftp->getLastSFTPError()` returns a string and `$sftp->getSFTPErrors()` returns an array, and that's what you have to echo in order to see what's wrong.

Try

```
print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
```

Comment: hey, mine fails to login and print_r($sftp->getLastSFTPError()); doesn't print out anything, and print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors()); just prints out an empty array. any idea about what might be causing the failure with no errors? thanks!